# Getting Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 Installed Properly with CUDA 8 and/or Using CUDA 8 without Visual Studio

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2015, cuda

For the past several days I have been trying to install Visual Studio 2015 update 3 and configure it for CUDA 8 without success, this is a two part question

1. I downloaded visual studio from here https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/older-downloads/, mounted the ISO on a windows 10 Lenovo laptop. It took A LONG TIME to install. Immediately I noticed that when you start a new project and hit okay, the window disappears and reappears over and over. Also when I open the developer command prompt it tells me my installation of visual studio is not found and doesn't recognize the command 'cl,' also. I've repaired, uninstalled, restarted, multiple times but it refuses to install correctly. I installed it on a non CUDA capable computer and it seemed to be working fine.
2. Onto CUDA, in visual studio almost every kernel in my .cu files was throwing compiler errors, this may have been my fault but I'm not sure. I was going to try and compile the .cu files from the command prompt but the vs command prompt is broken too. So is it possible to use the MSVCN (CUDA compiler, is that what it is?) or some other c++ compiler from the windows command line skipping the visual studio launch process, or is CUDA too tightly integrated with vs?

Comment: Actually there are two issues in your side, one is the VS setup issue, you need to collect the detailed setup log messages and share it here. For another CUDA issue, you could post the issue here:https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/board/58/. At least, you could know that what the requirements are if you want to use it.

Comment: My card is CUDA enabled, and CUDA is enabled for VS 2015 update 3. I will find the setup logs and post them here.

Comment: You could collect the log file using this tool: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=12493, and then you could upload the log file to one drive and share the download link in your new comment.

Comment: Thank you, will upload momentarily

Comment: The logs don't appear to be collecting correctly, they aren't appearing in my app data folder, I'm going to try and get them one more time then I'm probably going to try reinstalling windows.

Comment: I'm checking outside the app data folder just in case

Comment: Also could someone let me know why I've been downvoted? I'm new here.

Comment: The command collect.exe /? did not run so I'm more suspicious something is wrong with my installation of windows, I'm going to reinstall and see what happens.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After reinstalling windows and getting visual studio installed correctly CUDA seems to have installed correctly and is working.

Comment: ,Actually it is hard for us to make sure that whether it was the windows issue or the VS setup issue, anyway, since it was resolved now, you could mark it as the answer and close this case. Have a nice day.

Answer (score -1):

Reinstalling windows seems to have allowed visual studio to install correctly, projects create and run.